# Listview Datapager - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am using Listview to display products list from database. OnPage Load products gets load properly but when I try to switch page using datapager pagination it gives this error

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKeyArray.get_Item(Int32 index) at shop.products_ItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)

Thing is if I use ItemDataBound then only I get this error. Else paginations works fine.

```
<asp:ListView ID="products" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                              content
                            </ItemTemplate>

                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                                    <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="datapager">
                                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" PageSize="12" PagedControlID="products" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" ShowNextPageButton="false" ButtonCssClass="nextPre" />
                                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" ButtonCount="10" />

                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" ButtonCssClass="nextPre" />
                                        </Fields>
                                    </asp:DataPager>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </LayoutTemplate>

                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <strong>No Items Found....</strong>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

Item DataBound

```
private void products_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) {
                ListViewDataItem itm = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
                string productID = products.DataKeys(itm.DataItemIndex)("ID");
                query = "SELECT stock_status FROM products WHERE ID = '" + productID + "'";
                DataTable dt = this.GetData(query);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
                    ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("checkReadyStock")).Text = dt.Rows(0)("stock_status").ToString;

                    if (((Label)e.Item.FindControl("checkReadyStock")).Text == "Ready Stock") {
                        ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("readyStock")).Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
```

DataPager

```
protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    (products.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    products.DataSource = ViewState("Data");
    products.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in products_ItemDataBound. You should fix those first.

Comment: @VDWWD What errors?

Comment: When I copy the code from products_ItemDataBound into VS 2015 it gives 5 errors.

Comment: @VDWWD might be some other problem because it is working perfectly fine. You can see live site http://brandstik.in/Music . ItemDataBound is basically for image to display Ready Stock where it checks condition . If condition gets true then only it shows Ready Stock image there. See the link you will get proper idea.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this. You just have to change 'ColumnNameWithID' to the correct name.

```
protected void products_ItemDataBound1(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            string productID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ColumnNameWithID").ToString();
            string query = "SELECT stock_status FROM products WHERE ID = '" + productID + "'";
            DataTable dt = this.GetData(query);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("checkReadyStock")).Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                if (((Label)e.Item.FindControl("checkReadyStock")).Text == "Ready Stock")
                {
                    ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("readyStock")).Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean I should put name of column which is primarykey then ID is the name of that column which I did already

Comment: Yes that's right. For the sake of the example I used a more readable column name.